# prepare scrapy data for normalized postgresql database

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, pandas

I have build a postgresql data model to store football results. So I have the following tables with foreign keys linking them.

country table:
id,country

Club table:
id,id_country,club

Matches table:
gamedate,id_club_home,id_club_away,home_score,away_score

now I have my scraped data in a pandas dataframe, but with the following fields:

gamedate,country,home_club,away_club,home_score,away_score

So I want to insert this data in the 3 tables where it checks if the country and clubs already exist in the database, if not add them to the appropriate tables and then replace all text fields with the ids and insert the match data.

Is this best done by loading the country and club tables in python and transforming the data with pandas/python or is there a better/more efficient way. I hope to build this quite scalable to be able to quickly load large datasets to learn for future projects.

Comment: what is the problem? is it that you have different keys from the scraped data ? or is it that you have to transverse every time in the database to search for the country name? and then add?

Comment: I'm just not sure what is the best/quickest/most efficient way to do this. when you get unstructured data from a scraper and want to insert it into normalized SQL tables. Just looking for a general answer for the best approach.

Comment: this might be off but handling database with the data by scraping and then connecting to the server initializing variables seems a bit mess, i handled a large data form a shopping website(which was json) and then used MySql for storage, it wasn't fun, later i moved to Google's `firebase` have a look at it. easy database management and smooth stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I want to be able to combine statistics from multiple sources in one database and standarize the format so it easy to use for analysis. SQL seems perfect for it? so basically I want this:

standarize data from lots of websites --> store it somewhere --> easily retrieve it for analysis in python.

I got the standarized data model, got the method to get the data from the website, I know how to retrieve the data from the SQL database, I just don't know how to best get the data in the multiple database tables.

Comment: you can do that stuff in `firebase` too , actually the dataframe in which MySQL stores is the same as firebase, i.e. `json`(thought you can later convert that into `lxml` or `csv') ,and the issue about different tables, you can set up different parent nodes, and talking about retrieving and storing , it is between two lines. [check this out](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-firebase/1.2). now talking about tables from different databases, I don't specifically remember but you can do that by importing from the project option in the toolbar on top. 
cheers